# Standard algorithms for recognizing grammar productions correctness

Tags: grammar

I'm sure there's a standard way to do this, but I don't even know where to start searching for it.

How can i recognize, in any language, structures (grammars) in the form of, for example:

```
Exp ::= Number |(Exp) | Exp + Exp 
Number ::= Number Digit | Digit
Digit ::= 0 | ... | 9
```

I mean, given a string like `32 + (43 + 23)`, how can I tell if it's legal? Is there a standard algorithm or something? I don't know what to search for, so I wasn't able to search this site neither.

Comment: If you can convert the grammar to an LL1 grammar, you can use a LL1 parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are looking for parsing algorithm (membership algorithim)**. Parsing is the process of analyzing a string of language symbols in Formal Languages. And **Yes for any context-free-grammar** there is a possible parsing algorithm-that is **Brute-Force a fundamental algorithm but inefficient**, Like phrase-structure parsing, its worst-case complexity is O(n<sup>3</sup>) <sub>(you are to start from here)</sub> [**REFF1**](http://www.stanford.edu/~mjkay/covington.pdf) . But if grammar is in standard (restricted) form then more efficient algorithm is  possible. there are various parsing algorithms e.g. LL parser and LR parser..etc. [**REFFRENCE**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aParsing_algorithms)